# There's an error in <path> code and it's affecting the rest of my web page.Can anyone spot it? if so, your help would be much appreciated

Tags: svg, path, maps

The SVG file is an outline of the highland map in Scotland. The closing  reads like an error and is in red in Brackets. I'm using an SVG of the UK to reference from...If anyone has experience understanding the SVG file and sees where I've gone wrong, your help would be much appreciated.

```html
<svg class="img-fluid" baseprofile="tiny" fill="#008000" stroke="black"  version="1.2" viewbox="0 0 1000 1870" width="100%" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
<path d="M226.8 714.8l0 1.3 2.5 0-1.3 6.4-1.8 3.7-2.7 1.6-3.6 0.4-1.7-1-1.6-4.2-1.4-1-1.4-0.6-3-3.2-1.8-1 5.7-6.7 3-2.4 3.8-0.5 5 3.2 2.1 2.4-1.8 1.6z m-23.6-5.8l-3.1 0.5-3.1-0.1-2.5-0.6 1.5-1.3 3.3-2 1.8-0.4 1.1 1 2.3 0.6 1.2 0.9-2.5 1.4z m56.7-42.7l-3.2 1.3-2.5-1.1-2.2-2.3-0.6-2.5 2.3-1.4 3.3 0.7 2.5 2.5 0.4 2.8z m-5.5-36.7l-0.4 2.7-1.6 5.3-1.4 6.2 0.1 5.4 0.8 1.3 1.3 3 0.5 2.9-1.6 1.3-1.6 0.7-1.5 1.1-1.6 0.6-1.6-1.1 0.3-1.2 0.4-1.3-1-1.5-0.2-3 0.8-11.4 0.7-3 1.5-1.4 2.8-0.4 0-1.2-1.2-1.8-0.8-1.9 1.1-1.1 1-0.1 1.9 1.2 0-1.3-1.3-2.4 0.8 0.2 0.7 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.5 1z m1.4-6.5l0 2.8-1.5-0.8-0.6-1.8 0.2-2.4 1.1-2.3-0.4-0.5-0.2-0.8 0.6-1.1 0.7-0.8 0.7-0.1 0.6 0.9-1.2 6.9z m-33-30.3l0.9 1.9 0.8 1.1 2.3 1.9 0.9 1.2 2.3 4.1 0.4 0.8 4.3 3.7 1.8 2.4 1 1.7 0.4 1.5 0.9 12.5 0.9 5.3 0.2 2.5-0.3 2.7-0.8 4-0.2 2.4-0.5 1.4-2.6 2.5 0.3 0.4 1.6-1.1 1.7-0.6 1.5 0.5 0.8 1.8-0.6 1.7-1 1.5-0.6 1 0.5 3 1.4 1.8 1.5 1.3 0.6 1.3-0.7 1.6-3.3 2-1.3 1.2 8.3-1.1 2.1 0.6 0.5 1.5-1.2 1.6-2.4 1.2 0 1.2 2.6-0.3 2.1-1.1 2-0.2 2.1 2.2 0.9 0.7 1.3 0.1 2.4-0.2 1.5 0.7 0.9 1.6 0.6 1.7 0.6 0.9 1.4 0.2 0.9-0.8 0.6-1.2 0.5-0.7 4 0.2 2.7-2.8 2.7-1 2.8 0 1.6 2.3 7.2 0-1.6 4.4 0 1.1 0.4 2-0.3 1.7-0.8 1.4-1.9 2.7-3.5 3-1.5 0.7-3.8 0.4-0.6 1.2-0.2 3.9-0.9 2.5-2 1.6-2.1 1.2-0.9 0.8-0.8 1.4-5.6 8-1.5 1.6-1.8 1.2-5.1 1-1.4-0.6-0.9-2.3 0.3-3 2.6-3.9-0.3-1.5 0-1.3 0.9-0.8 0.7-2.5 0.6-0.8 1.8-3.4 0.8-1.2 1.1-1 9.3-4.8 0-1.2-2.7 1.5-2.7 0.8-8.2 0.2-0.5-0.5-0.2-2.3-0.2-1-2.2-3.9-1.3-1.5-1.1-0.7 0.4 1.9 0.4 1.4 1.1 2.8-1 2.6-0.6 1.2-1 1 0.7 1.4-1.2 1.4-0.8 2-0.9 1.7-1.4 0.8-1.2-1.4-0.6-3.1-0.4-3.6-0.1-2.7-0.8-0.9-0.5-0.3-1.4 1.2-0.7-1.1-0.7-0.7-0.9-0.5-0.9-0.1 0 1.1 1.4 1.4-1.7 1.2-13.6 3.6 0-1.4 1.1-0.9 2.9-3.9 0-1.1-1.8-0.1-1.7 0.5-1.6 0.8-1.5 1.2-1.8-2.8-1.5-3.3 1.1-0.5 0.9-0.7 0.7-0.9 0.6-1.5-4.4 0.5-1.6-0.5-4.5-6.1-1.1-3.1-1.2-1.7-0.3-1.3 4.4-3.2 1.9-0.8 2.2 0.3 1.7 1.6 1.7 2.1 2 1.8 2.5 0.6-1.2-2.3-6-5.1-1.3-1.5-0.6-0.6-1.1-0.2-1.1 0.2-2.1 0.9-1.2 0 1.4-1.1 0-1.3-0.7-0.2-1.9-1 1-0.6 0.2-0.7-0.8-0.4-0.7-1-0.2-1.4 0.5-2-1.4 0.4-1.9 2.4-1.3 0.8 0.5-1.5 0.1-1.7-0.4-1.6-0.9-1.4-0.8 2.4-1.1 0.7-1.1 0.5-0.9 1.4-0.1 2.1 1 3.2-0.2 2-1.5 1.4-8.9-3.1-2.2-1.5-1.8-2.1-0.8-2.6-0.9-4.6-3.9-3.1-1.1-4 5.9 0-1.3-1.5-0.9-1.9-0.1-2.2 0.7-2.3 1.3-1.9 1-0.5 0.9 0.6 5 7.5 0.6 1.7 0.9 1.1 1.8 1.4 1.2 0.3-0.5-2.3 0-1.1 1.2-1.2-1.6-2-1.4-2.3-0.2-0.7 0.2-0.8 0.9-0.3 0.2-0.7 0.8-0.8 1.7 0.2 2.8 1.3-0.9-3.2-2.5-2.9-2.9-1.9-2.4-0.7 1.3-1.7 1-2.7 0.2-2.6-1.1-1.5 0-1.4 2 0.1 1.3 1.3 1.1 1.6 2.1 1.5 0.4 1.4 0.2 1.7 0.2 1.1 0.9 1.2 0.7 0.5 4.5 2.5 1 0.9 1.1 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.2-0.1 1.4-0.7 1.6-0.2-2.2 5.4 1 0.3 2-2.7 1.2-3.5 1.2 0.7 7.3 9.7 0-1.2-0.4-0.6-0.9-1.8 0-2.5-1.3-2.2-3.3-4-1.6-3.7 0.3-1.9 1.3-1.7 1.2-3.7-1.1 0.2-1.1-0.2-0.9-0.5-0.7-0.7 0.4-2.5-0.5-1.4-0.8-1.1-0.5-1.2-0.1-2.1 0.2-0.6 0.7-0.2 3.8-2.5 0.6-0.7 0.9-2.1 0.5-2.2 0.7-1.3 1.3 0.6 1-0.6 0.3-0.6z m245.5 13.7l1.6 3.7 0.9 3.7 1.9 1.4 0 2-0.7 1.2 0.6 1.8-0.1 3 2.3 1.8 0.6 2.6 0.2 2.7-0.8 5.6 0.2 2.8-3.3 4.1-0.4 2.1 0.5 1 1.6-0.4 3.4-4.1 5.4-0.6 1.4-1.9 1.7-0.7 7.7-1.6 5.7 5.6 3.9 0.9 1.3 7.1-0.6 2-2.7 2.2-2.6 5.1-2.6 2.1-1.3 2.2 0.3 1.1 3.6 2.3-0.9 8.7 3.3 2.5-0.9 1.8 0.3 1.8-0.9 2.5-1.6 1.9-2.1-0.1-5.4 2.6-2.4 3.2-3 1.9-2.6 3.1-2.6 0.3-3.3 3.4-0.3 0.2-5.6 3.2-0.7 1.9 0.5 1.1-0.9 5.7 0.3 6.4-0.8 1.8-2.6 3-1.5 6-1.9-0.7-5.9 1.7-2-0.6-4-3.4-0.9 0.7-1 2.5-0.6 5.2-0.9 0.7-5.5-1.2-6.4 1.3-6.2-2.4-1.3 0.2-2.3 2.6 0.6 3.1-0.5 1-5 2.9-4.8 1.4-2.9 3.7-3.2-0.5-1.1 0.8-0.3 0.5-1.2 1.1-4.2 6.1-1 0-2.6-1.3-1.9-2.9-1.9-0.2-2.9 4.5-0.7 2.5-2.6 1.5 0.5 4.8-2 2-0.3 1.3 1.1 2.8-5.7 3-5.5 0.9-0.6 1.3 0 3.8-4.6-0.4-3.3-1.8-7 1.2-3-1.7-2.8-0.5-4.5 2.7-4.7 0.6-1.8 3-2.1 0.9-1.4 1.9-6.7-1.6-2.3-2.5-12.3-1.6-0.7 0 0.6-1.1-1.9-1.3 0-1.3 0.9-0.5 2.1-1.9 2.4 0.3 1.3-0.1 2.8-2.6 2.2 0 4.1 1.3 2-0.6 3.8-2.5 7.7-1.8 1.7-1.2-15.9 3.5-7.4-3.6-0.1-1 1-2.5 0.6-0.8 6.5-7.2 1.7-2.9 1.6-3.4-5.7 5.1-0.8 1.4-0.4 1.1-1 1-1.2 0.7-1 0.3-0.8 0.5-0.3 1.3-0.2 1.5-0.3 1.4-1.3 2.6-1.2 1.5-1.5 0.7-1.7 0.1-0.8 0.4-0.9 1.6-2 0.7-0.8 1.1-1.1 2.1-2.7 3.5-1.5 1-2 0.4-1 0.7-1.4 3.2-0.9 0.7-1.2 0.4-1.1 0.9-1 1.2-3.9 5.8-6.3 7.7-6.6 5.3-0.6 0.3-0.9-0.7-1.1-2.3-1-0.5-1.6-0.3-1.8-0.8-1.7-1.2-1.1-1.4 1.4-2.8 0.4-1.4 0.2-1.7-0.7 0-3.6 5-5.8-1.3-14.3-11.9-0.6-1.3 0.1-2.8 1-1.3 1.4-0.5 4.8-0.4 3.3 0.7 3.1 1.6 2.6 2.7 0.8-1.3-2.3-1.9-1-1.2 0-1.7 10.2-6.9 2.3-0.3 6 3.2 2.5 0.5 5.1-0.4 2.8-0.7 2-1.4-8.9 1.2-2.1-0.4-4.8-3.1-4-1-10.5 5.8-3.6 1.1-1 0-1.2-0.5-2.2-1.6-1.2-0.3-6.7 0.5-7.1-1.9-2.4 0.2-1.9 1.9-1.7 1.1-2.4-0.5-2.2-1.3-1.3-1.2-0.9-1.9-0.3-1-0.1-1.2 0.2-1.7 0.5-0.1 0.6 0.4 0.7-0.5 2.1-3.3 1.3-1 14.7-1.6 1.2-0.6 3.3-2.6 1.4-0.5 1.7 0.4 1 0.9 0.9 1.3 1.4 1.1 5.1 2.2 0.8 0.7-0.1-1.9-0.5-1.9-1-1.3-1.7-0.2 0-1.3 1.2-0.2 1.2 0.1 1.1 0.5 1 0.9 1.4-1.8 2.2-0.8 4.4 1.3-7.2-3.6-1.9-2.3 0-1.9 1.3-1.3 10-1.5 3.9-1.7 3.1-3.2-1.2-0.6-1.8 0.2-1.6 0.8-1.5 3-2-0.1-3.7-1 0.8-1.8 3.8-4.2-4.3-0.8-9.1 2-4.4-1.2 3.2-0.9 3.4-0.2 0-1.3-0.7-0.5-2-2 1.7-2.1 1.1-3.6 0.8-4.1 1.1-3.5 1.7-2.2 2.7-1.9 2.9-1.1 2.5 0.5 0.9 1.1 1.9 3.5 1.1 1.4 1.4 1.1 1.5 0.7 3.2 0.5 5.2-1.2 4.6-2.4 0-1.2-1.7 0.5-1.5 0.9-1.4 0.5-1.3-0.7-2.2 1.5-2-0.5-2.1-1.4-1.9-0.8-1.5-1 0.4-2.2 0.1-2.5-2.1-1.5-0.8 0.1-2 0.9-1.1 0.2-0.9-0.4-1.7-1.7-1-0.3-1-1.3 1.4-3 4-5.2 1.1-1.9 0.7-0.7 1.2-0.1 2.8 0.3 1-0.8 1.7-1 2.4 0.9 4.1 3.1 1.9 1.1 9.5 0.1 1.2-1.8 1.6-0.1 1.6 0.4 0.6 0.3 0.7 0 0-1.3-1.9-1.2-8.1 1.4-2.2 0.9-1.3 0.2-0.7-0.6-2.4-3.2-1.1-1-8.1-2.5-1.2-1.8 0.7-3 3.4-4.9 1.3-2.4-1.8-3 2.3-3.4 4-2.6 3.3-0.7 3.1 2.3 3 3.7 3.3 2.5 3.7-1.3 0-1.2-4-0.9-0.9-0.8-1.4-2.6-0.9-1.2-1-0.5-0.9-1.2 1.3-2.7 2.3-2.5 2.3-0.9 0-1.3-2.3-1-1.6 1.4-1.2 2.2-1.2 1.1-1.6 0.6-3.4 2.4-1.9 0.7-2-0.3-3.7-1.7-1.9-0.5-4.1 1.4-2-0.1-0.8-2.5 0.4-0.6 2.2-5.5 0.8-0.8 2.1-1.3 0.8-0.9 0.9-0.8 0.7 0.7 0.5 1.2 0.5 0.6 2.3-0.4 10.7-5.1 4.3-4.1 0.8-5-1.6-0.4-2.6 2.7-4.4 6.2-2.5 2-2.2-0.4-2.3-1.1-2.8-0.5 2.3-1.5 0.8-1.2-0.2-1.5-0.8-2.2-0.2-1.2-0.4 0.1-1.5 1.5-6.5 8.6-2.4 1.2-5 0.8-2.2-1.2-1.7-7 0.3 0.2 0.9-0.9 0.1-0.5-1.1-2-0.2-0.6 0-2.4 0.3-1.1 1-1.2-1-0.6-2.9-0.9-0.7-0.4-0.2-1.9-0.9-3.1-0.2-2.3 0.3-1.3 1.3-3 0.4-1.2 0.1-2.5 0-2.3 0.4-1.4 1.5 0-0.8-3.6 1.8-0.7 1.7 0.3 1.6 1.1 5.2 5.4 1.6 1.2 0.8-0.7 1.7 2.6 0.8 0.6 2.9 2.1 1.1 0.3-0.5-1-0.8-2.7 6.9-1.2 4 0.7 2.2-0.1 0.4-1.2-2.9-2.5-4.4-1-4.2 0.6-2.7 2.4-3.3-3.9 0.6-0.6 0.7-1.7-3.2-0.7-1.6-2.8-1.2-3.5-1.8-2.9-1.5-0.6-1.5-0.2-1.2-0.7-0.5-2.2 0.6-2.2 1.9-2.2-0.5-1.7 0-1.3 3.6-2.1 1.8 0 2.8 3.2 1.2-0.2 1-1.4 0.8-1.9-1.1-0.4-0.6-0.9-0.7-1.2-0.9-1.1-1.2-0.7-8-1.9-0.3-1.9 0.5-4.7-0.2-2.1 0.3-1.5-0.8-3.6-0.2-2.3 0.4-1.9 0.7-1.8 1-1.5 1.3-1.1 2.4-0.9 2.5-0.1 2.5 0.8 2.4 1.6-0.4 2.4 0.3 3.6 0.7 3.6 0.7 2.7 1 1.9 1.2 1.3 1.5 0.8 1.6-0.1-0.8-0.8-0.4-0.9-0.7-2.2 1.2-0.1 0.9 0.3 1.8 1.1-0.6-3.5 0.4-2.6 0.1-2.3-1.3-2.8-3.7-3.5-1.2-2 1-1.9-0.8-0.2-0.5-1 0.9-1.7 2.2-3 0.8-1.5 1.4 1.8 1 0.7 3.6 0-0.6 5 2.7 3.6 4 2.1 3 0.4-0.5-1.2 1.1-1.6 1.2-5.1 0.9-2 1.2 0.1 4.4 1.9 1.3 1.1 2.7 3.3 3.2 2 7 2.7-1.5-2.5-1-1.1-2.8-1.3-4.3-4.4-6.1-2.8-0.8-0.8-0.4-1.9 0.4-1.2 0.6-0.1 0.7 0.8 0.7 0.1 0.6-2.1 1.8 1.1 2.7 4 2.1 1.1 1.1 0 1.8-1 1-0.2 1.2 0.4 2.2 1.6 0.9 0.4 1.2 0.7 3.6 3.5 4 1.9 2.8 5 1.9 1.3-0.5-1-0.7-1.6-0.5-1.7-0.3-1.3-0.5-1.2-9.6-8.5-2.3-0.6 0-1.4 1.9 0.1 0.7-1.4-0.1-2.1-0.9-2.2-1.2-1.1-3.1-0.6-1.3-1.3-2.9-0.7-3.9-5.1-2.5-0.5 0.7-1.1-1.4-2.1-1.9-0.7-3.9 0.3 0.7-2 0.6-0.6 0-1.3-3.2-5.8 1.8-2.4 3.7 1 2.3 4.8 2.1-1.8 2 0.7 2.2 0.3 2.3-2.9-0.6 0 0.4-1.8 0-1.7-0.5-1.5-0.7-1.2 1.4 0 0-1.3-2-1.3 1.3-1 2.7-0.7 1.3-0.7 0-1.4-3.2 0.2-1.5-0.4-1.3-1 0.7-1.2-0.7-0.9-0.8-0.7-0.9-0.5-0.9-0.3 0.5-3 0.2-0.9-1.2 0-1-0.7-4.4-6.9 0.1-3 1.5-0.5 2.2 0.9 4.1 2.9 1.6 0.4 1.6-0.4 3.9-2.6 2-0.7 2.1 0.2 2 1.7 0.7-1.3 1.3-1.2 1.4-0.9 0.8-0.3 1.7 0.5 2.9 2.6 1.3 0.6 4.8-0.4 1.5 0.4 6.6 5.1-0.9-1.9-1.1-1.2-2.6-2 1.2-1.1 2.8-0.5 1.3-0.9-6.1-1.2-1.9 0-0.8 0.5-1.1 1.6-1 0.3-1-0.3-2-1.7-1-0.4-1.4-1-2.9-4.3-0.9-1-0.2-0.7-1.8-2.8-0.3-0.3-0.8-2.4-0.5-2.6 1.9 0-1-2 0.1-1.8 0.7-1.8 0.9-2 0.1-0.9-0.2-2.3 0.4-0.4 0.7 0.2 1.3 0.8 0.6 0.1 5.6 4 4-0.2-2.7-2.2-0.9-1.2 0.3-1.5-0.6-1.3-0.9 0.9-1 0.5-1 0.1-1.1-0.2 0-1.3 1.3 0 0-1.3-0.7-0.1-1.3-1.3 5.3-3.1 2.4 1.1 2.9 2-10.6-9.3 0-3.4 0.2-1.5 0.7-0.9 5.1-3.1 1.5-1.5 1.1-2.9-0.7 0 0.8-3.8 0.3-3.7 0.7-3.2 1.6-2 12.3 2.8 2.3 1.5 1.7 2.3 0 0.9 0.5 2.9 0.6 2.5 0.3-0.2-0.1 2.1-0.2 1.6-0.5 1.4-0.6 1.3 1.8-1.4 0.7-1.7 0.2-1.9 0-1.9 0.4-2.7 0.8-1.2 0.6-1.3-0.5-3.1 1.7 1.5 3 4 1.6 0.8 2.7 2.1 1.2 0.4 1 0.7 0.1 1.5-0.4 1.7-0.4 1.2-1.1 1.5-3.4 3.3-1.8 4.7-1.8 3.4-0.9 2.5 1.8-0.3 5.7-6.4 0.9-0.5 0.6-2.9 1.6-1.3 1.9-0.9 1.8-1.8 1.1-3.1 0.5-3.4 1-2.6 2.3-1 4.2 0.8 4 1.8 4.7 3.5 0 1.4-0.2 0.8 0.2 1.8-2.2 2.7-1.5 3.3-1.2 3.8-1.7 4 1.7-0.7 1.6-1.6 2.6-3.9 0.1-0.8-0.1-1.5 0.8-0.6 3.9-4.3 0.2-0.4 3.8-2.6 2.5-1.2 1-0.2 1.9 0.7 2.9 2.7 2.1 0.6-1.3-1.3 1-0.8 1-2.2 0.6-0.7 1.1-0.2 1.9 1 1.3 0.2 0.8-0.5 0.8-2.4 1-0.6 3.7 0 2 0.6 0.9 0.1 1-0.7 0.9-1.3 1.2-3.1 0.9-0.6 0.8-0.2 0.3 0.2 1.8 3.6 0.5 0.5 2.2-0.5 8.2 1.4 8.2-1.4 4.2-1.9 6.5-5.1 3.7-1.8 6-1.1 3.1 0 2.2 1.1-1.3 1.3 2.3 2.2 2.7-0.3 5.5-1.9 5.3 2.4 2.6 0 1.3-3.7-1.6-0.7-1.8-1.3-1.5-1.9-1-2.5 2.1-3 1.5-1 1.6 0.3 0.4 1 0.2 1.7 0.4 1.7 0.7 0.7 2.9 0 6.3-2 3.9-0.4 5 3.6 3.2 0.1 6.3-1.3 3.3 1.4-0.6 3.4-1.9 3.8-0.4 2.7-1.1 1.5-1.4 3.4-0.9 1.5-2.5 2.5-0.7 1.2-1.1 3.5 0 3 1 2.2 2 1.3 1.2-0.1 1.1-0.7 0.9-0.2 0.8 1 0.3 2.2-0.4 1.6-0.9 1-1 0.3-0.9 6.5-4.2 8.3-5 7.4-3.7 4.2-4 2.4-8.4 3-3.4 2.1-5.1 5.2-0.8 1.7-0.8 3-1.8 3.1-4 4.5-21.1 17.5-7.1 3.7-1.8 1.8-0.8 1.9-0.9 3.7-0.6 1.3-0.8 0.9-2.4 1.4-3.1 0.7-6.1 4.3-1 0.6-0.6 1.1-0.4 1.5 0 1.9-1.6-0.9-0.4-0.4 0.6-1.2-1.3-0.7-2.5-0.3-2.7-1.7-0.5 0.8 0.3 1.5 0.8 1.6 1.5 1.1 2.9 0.1 1.5 0.7 0.7 0.8 2 3.5-2 3.4-0.5 1.9 0.5 2-1.5 0-2.9-1.1-1.5 0-0.8 0.7-1.7 2.3-0.8 0.7-2.7-0.1-5.5-2.9-2.7-0.7-7.7 2.1-2.1-1.5-3.1-4.4-1.9-1.7-1.9-0.7 5.1 7.7 3 2.6 3.7 0.8 3.9-1.8 2-0.4 1.7 1.6 1.6 2.1 2.3 1.6 1.6 0-0.6-3.1 6.2 4.3 3.3 0.9 5.5-4.3 3 0.7 1.7 2.3-1.3 2.3 3.2 0.9 3.5-1.6 3.5-3.3 2.7-4 1.4-1.7 1.2 0.2 0.7 1.7-0.3 3-0.8 1.6-13 17.2-2.2 1.8-2.5 3.9-1.3 1.3-1.9 0.4-1.5-0.7-0.5-1.8 1.2-2.8-2.6-2.5-3.3 1.2-7.4 6.8-1.3 0.6-2.5 0.1-6.2 1.8-1.8-0.3-1.6 0.1-0.7 2-0.7 2.5-1.4 1.2-1.4 0.6-6.2 6.3-0.9 1.2-0.8 1.8-0.8 2.8 0.5 0.1 1.3-1 2.9-1.2 1.4-1.5 1.4-1.8 0.9-1.7 1.2-1.7 4.4-2.7 3.7-3.9 4.1-2.1 0.8-0.1 1.1 0.5 1.2 1.6 4.9 1.1 2.1-0.1 1.5-1.2 1.2-1.3 4.2-2.7 1.5-0.3 0.4 2.3-2 3.7-2.7 3.5-2.8 2.3-3.4 5.4 0.6 1.6 0.7 0.9-4.5 0.4-1.8 1.1-1.6 2.1 0.9 1.7-0.7 0.2-2.2-0.7-5.2 0 0 1.4 2.7-0.1 1.3 0.3 1.2 0.9-1.8 4.1-1 1.8-1.1 1.4 3.4 0.9 1.8 0.1 2-1 1.5-2 0.8-1.1 0-0.6 2.2-0.1 1-0.6 1.8-2.6 1.4-1.4 1.5-1 1.4-0.4 1.7-0.8-1.1-2-3.6-3.3 2.7 0.2 8.8-1.4 9.2 0.9 3-0.9 7.9-6z" id="GBR2745" name="Highland">
</path>
</svg>
```

Comment: Can you add your code?

Comment: Sorry about that, It's weird but the code doesn't seem to be dis-functioning on stack

Comment: This is a valid SVG. Maybe you have something else in your code that gives you error